# Testthat: create shared variables between unit tests which don't survive the test file

Tags: r, unit-testing, scope, testthat

I have a piece of sequential code and I would like to test every piece of it.
The problem is that each piece needs the output of the precedent one as input.

`testthat::test_that()` calls encapsulate the code and therefore every variable created in it gets destroyed after the test.
I thought of using `<<-` but it puts the variables in the global environment even if I wrap all the tests in a `local()` call.
Also I would like these variables not to survive each test file, so that I'm sure of what I am testing.

Here some test code:

```
local({
    test_that('test 1', {
        foo <<- 1
        expect_equal(foo, 1)
    })

    test_that('test 1', {
        bar <- foo + 1
        expect_equal(bar, 2)
    })
})

print(exists("foo")) # should not exists but it does
print(exists("bar"))
```

I'd like to use "foo" in the second test but be sure that it doesn't get in the global env and doesn't leave the test file.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for `<<-` is that it looks up the environment tree until it finds the variable, and assigns in `globalenv()` if that search fails.  So you just have to make sure the search succeeds and you won't leave leftovers:

```
local({
    foo <- NULL  # so that the <<- assignment stays local

    test_that('test 1', {
        foo <<- 1
        expect_equal(foo, 1)
    })

    test_that('test 1', {
        bar <- foo + 1
        expect_equal(bar, 2)
    })
})

print(exists("foo")) # should not exist, and doesn't!
print(exists("bar"))
```

Comment: Eventually I started using env <- parent.env(environment()) to get the parent environment into a test to be able to attach variables to it. it seems to work fine!